# A fix to not crash a map created with a multidimensional vector

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, multidimensional-array

I am trying to create a map where you as a player can move through the map using up,down,left & right keys and so far im in the right path. What bothers me is that everytime I reach an element outside its vector scope it errors me out saying

> vector subscript out of range

and I know what this means so I'm figuring out a solution to solve this but how am I supposed to do this? Making an if statement telling that if it reaches a certain element it should not increment the value of `moveY` and just `return false`

This code below me does not work.. :/

```
bool Map::Player_Pos(float posY, float posX)
{
    this->map[posY][posX] = '#';
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(0x28))
    {
        if (moveY == 10)
        {
            return false;
        }
        this->map[posY][posX] = '.';
        moveY += 1;
    }
    return true;
}
```

The problem lies at `bool Player_Pos(float posY, float posX);` so any suggestions would be really appreciated!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <Windows.h>

class Map
{
private:
    float moveY = 0.f;
    float moveX = 0.f;
    std::vector<std::vector<char>> map;
public:
    Map(int dim1, int dim2, char type) 
    {
        map.resize(dim1, std::vector<char>(dim2, type));
    }

    bool Update()
    {
        system("cls");
        for (int i = 0; i < map.size(); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < map.size(); j++)
            {
                std::cout << map[i][j];
            }
            std::cout << '\n';
        }
        return true;
    }

    bool Player_Pos(float posY, float posX);

    float posY() { return moveY; }
    float posX() { return moveX; }
};

bool Map::Player_Pos(float posY, float posX)
{
    this->map[posY][posX] = '#';
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(0x28))
    {
        if (moveY == 10) // This does not work! Still keeps going and crashes compiler
        {
            return false;
        }
        this->map[posY][posX] = '.';
        moveY += 1;
    }
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    Map map = Map(10, 10, '.');  

    while (true)
    {
        map.Player_Pos(map.posY(), map.posX()); // Initialize position
        map.Update(); // Update map
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am looking at your code for any attempt at testing posX, posY to see if they are in range...  There aren't any.  That's why the code crashes.

Comment: If you want to index a `vector` why `float`s? All sorts of things can go wrong with floating point numbers. The most common would be truncation giving you an off-by-one error.